# remove a varchar2 string from the middle of table data values

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

Data in the `file_name` field of the generation table should be an assigned number, then _01, _02, or _03, etc. and then `.pdf` (example 82617_01.pdf).

Somewhere, the program is putting a state name and sometimes a date/time stamp, between the assigned number and the 01, 02, etc. (82617_ALABAMA_01.pdf or 19998_MAINE_07-31-2010_11-05-59_AM.pdf or 5485325_OREGON_01.pdf for example).

We would like to develop a SQL statement to find the bad file names and fix them.  In theory it seems rather simple to find file names that include a `varchar2` data type and remove it, but putting the statement together is beyond me.

Any help or suggestions appreciated.

Something like:

```
UPDATE GENERATION

SET FILE_NAME (?)

WHERE FILE_NAME (?...LIKE '%STRING%');?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the problem rows like this:

```
select *
from Files
where length(FILE_NAME) - length(replace(FILE_NAME, '_', '')) > 1
```

You can fix them like this:

```
update Files
set FILE_NAME = SUBSTR(FILE_NAME, 1, instr(FILE_NAME, '_') -1) ||
    SUBSTR(FILE_NAME, instr(FILE_NAME, '_', 1, 2))
where length(FILE_NAME) - length(replace(FILE_NAME, '_', '')) > 1
```

[SQL Fiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/07ccc/2)

Comment: Perfect............  took me a bit to grasp exactly what is going on, but it worked great right off the bat.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `Regexp_replace` function:

```
SQL> with t1(col) as(
  2      select '82617_mm_01.pdf' from dual union all
  3      select '456546_khkjh_89kjh_67_01.pdf' from dual union all
  4      select '19998_MAINE_07-31-2010_11-05-59_AM.pdf' from dual union all
  5      select '5485325_OREGON_01.pdf' from dual
  6     )
  7   select col
  8        , regexp_replace(col, '^([0-9]+)_(.*)_(\d{2}\.pdf)$', '\1_\3') res
  9     from t1;

COL                                     RES
 -------------------------------------- -----------------------------------------
82617_mm_01.pdf                         82617_01.pdf
456546_khkjh_89kjh_67_01.pdf            456546_01.pdf
19998_MAINE_07-31-2010_11-05-59_AM.pdf  19998_MAINE_07-31-2010_11-05-59_AM.pdf
5485325_OREGON_01.pdf                   5485325_01.pdf
```

To display good or bad data `regexp_like` function will come in handy:

```
SQL> with t1(col) as(
  2      select '826170_01.pdf' from dual union all
  3      select '456546_01.pdf' from dual union all
  4      select '19998_MAINE_07-31-2010_11-05-59_AM.pdf' from dual union all
  5      select '5485325_OREGON_01.pdf' from dual
  6     )
  7   select col bad_data
  8     from t1
  9   where not regexp_like(col, '^[0-9]+_\d{2}\.pdf$');

BAD_DATA
--------------------------------------
19998_MAINE_07-31-2010_11-05-59_AM.pdf
5485325_OREGON_01.pdf

SQL> with t1(col) as(
  2      select '826170_01.pdf' from dual union all
  3      select '456546_01.pdf' from dual union all
  4      select '19998_MAINE_07-31-2010_11-05-59_AM.pdf' from dual union all
  5      select '5485325_OREGON_01.pdf' from dual
  6     )
  7   select col good_data
  8     from t1
  9   where regexp_like(col, '^[0-9]+_\d{2}\.pdf$');

GOOD_DATA
--------------------------------------
826170_01.pdf
456546_01.pdf
```

To that end your `update` statement might look like this:

```
update your_table 
   set col = regexp_replace(col, '^([0-9]+)_(.*)_(\d{2}\.pdf)$', '\1_\3');
 --where clause if needed
```

Comment: Working through this may take me another day or two, but I am sure it is going to work for me as well....  Thank you very much for the help!!